# Does Wolverine still get his adamantium skeleton after Days of Future Past?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

At the end of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, we see

> Stryker pulling Wolverine out of that river. But Stryker turns out to be Mystique...

What I'm wondering is:

> if Stryker doesn't get his hands on Wolverine, does Wolverine ever get his adamantium bone job?

Plus I guess this is now an alternate time line, so there's probably no canon that covers this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The fact that Mystique rescues him does not mean that Striker and Wolverine don't work together later.

Comment: @phantom42 Yeah I guess that is probably the most likely answer. I was just hoping there might have been a detail I had missed somewhere.

Comment: Related: [Does Wolverine still have his adamantium claws after the change in events?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21312/49)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Wolverine will still likely end up with an adamantium skeleton. There is simply too much time between when he is recovered and when we see him in the future for such a continuity gap to occur.

- The movie's creators went through a great deal of trouble to correct previous "editorial choices" i.e. the deaths of Xavier and Jean Grey to allow Wolverine to go without his trademark adamantium skeleton.
- The changes that occur in the timeline don't remove any of the people involved with the Weapon X program. As we are told during the story, time favors a particular result. You can cause a disruption in the river and still not change its path.

**It simply says for the moment, Wolverine is rescued by Mystique instead of Stryker.** Since Stryker is still alive the potential for Weapon X, a program derived from the same program which created Captain America (in the canon Marvel Universe) still has a possibility to exist. Trask is also still alive and given that Stryker and Trask know each other, there is nothing stopping them from working together in the future if they can get a fiscal benefactor.

As a matter of fact:

- Given the events depicted in 'Days of Future Past' I can see the government, while publicly promoting peace and good will among humans and mutants (evidenced by the filled to capacity scene at Xavier's school) may still promote some other means of creating defenses against Magneto or someone like him.
- Since mutant powers have such a range of capacities, the government may decide to recruit mutants to work for it as part of a defense initiative. This may be the very catalyst in that time line to create the Weapon X program.

**UPDATE: With the release of X-Men Apocalypse:**

> We are re-introduced to Weapon X (Hugh Jackman reprises the role of Wolverine) being held in a mountain fastness by presumably Stryker and other agencies. Weapon X is released and has adamantium claws and anger management issues.

Comment: I really like that even though this question is mostly opinion based, you have saved it with an excellent and well researched answer! +1 mate.

Comment: Its also worth noting there is a 2 year gap between the end of Days of Future Past (1973) and when Wolverine meets Stryker for the "first" time in X-Men Origins after being put in front of a firing squad (1975). A lot can happen in 2 years.

Comment: Excellent answer Thaddeus! Cheers!

Comment: With the release and his presences spoiled by the trailer, it is important to highlight that we know Weapon X was in the Alkali Lake facility, the mountain vastness.

Answer (score 15):

There is no answer for this question... All that we can do is speculate...

> Since the timeline is altered heavily due to the actions throughout the movie Wolverine is shown at the end talking to Professor X saying so I'm a history teacher... and he proceeds to say that he needs help regarding history since it probably changed.. Everything after that year that was they were at.  So because history is heavily altered there's quite a few things that may have been altered.  The entire origin movie for Wolverine regarding how he got his skeleton most likely changed, the events of The Wolverine might still have happened considering he saved the Asian Guy in 1945, and pretty much all of the original X-Men movies probably did not happen as far as we know.  Granted that similar stuff might have happened because at the end of the movie you see quite a few of the characters from previous X-Men films at the academy in the future such as Rogue, Iceman, Jean, Cyclops, Professor X, and Beast.  As far as Wolverine getting his adamantium skeleton, we definitely do not know yet... Most likely in future X-Men movies this will be reconciled.

The only thing we know for sure is that the timelines divert as evidenced by this graphic of the timeline.

[image]

Comment: This is a great timeline - would you know if there is an updated version with events in Apocalypse?

Comment: I'd have to check. I haven't seen the Apocalypse yet either lol.

Comment: http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline#cite_ref-XMA_9-0

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, Wolverine still ends up getting his adamantium claws.

They can be seen in one of the recent trailers for *X-Men: Apocalypse*, which takes place 10 years after the past-events of *Days of Future Past*.

[image: Adamantium Claws]

[Simon Kinberg explains to Cinemablend](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-X-Men-Screenwriter-Resolves-Wolverine-Mystery-From-End-Days-Future-Past-131267.html) that <del>life</del> time finds a way, and Wolverine still somehow ends up working with Stryker and getting his claws, but that the hows-and-whys will be left unexplained.

> One of the things we talk about in *Days of Future Past* - there’s a scene where Hank/Beast talks about the immutability of time. Basically, you can change the way the future goes, but it finds its way back. So while we don’t show how, it found its way back to Wolverine being part of Weapon X and under the thumb of Stryker, that’s the idea.

Answer (score -12):

All is wrong.

Remember striker got mystique's DNA? He already turn himself into another mystique. As for how come he turn into mutant since he hates mutant so much?? It's because history is changed. Therefore wolverine still will have his nice metal claws.

Comment: That's some bold statements. Do you have anything to back them up?