# Is X-Men Origins: Wolverine canon?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, canon, x-men-origins-wolverine

At the beginning of [*X-Men Origins: Wolverine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine) we see that Logan (a.k.a. Wolverine) and Colonel William Stryker were working together by the end of the Vietnam War.

For 5 years after the war, he lives in Canada with a girlfriend. But in [*X-Men: Days of Future Past*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past) we see that Logan was part of some gang at the end of the Vietnam War.

**My question is which of these are *X-Men* movie canon?**

Answer (score 14):

[Reusing the image from this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/57259/20155), its possible for *X-Men Origins: Woverine* and *X-Men: Days of Future Past* to be consistent.

The majority of past events in Days of Future Past occur in 1973. However, [in Origins we only see Wolverine in Vietnam in 1975](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins%3A_Wolverine) when he and Sabertooth are put in front of a firing squad. Its possible Wolverine may have briefly returned home during that time, or not joined the war until quite late.

Either way, there is no strict on-screen overlap in time that prevents both movies from having occurred.

[image]

Comment: When Wolverine and Stryker see each other in DOFP, Wolverine obviously recognizes Stryker, but there is no indication of Stryker recognizing Wolverine. If Wolverine was just off-mission from his time with Stryker's group, there should have been some recognition on Stryker's part. It's more likely that Wolverine just joined up late, or had otherwise not started working with Stryker yet.

Comment: Would be worth updating this answer since the new *Deadpool* movie came out--according to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115869/22250) the new movie is part of the same continuity as DOFP, but it's also clearly incompatible with the different version of Deadpool (with a different origin) presented in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

Answer (score 7):

No, as of the release of *Days of Future Past*, Fox no longer considers *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* to be canon. The series producer, Lauren Donner, made this statement in [an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsyvZDlJpeA) at the premier of *Days of Future Past*, in which she said:

> “Just forget about ‘X3’ and the first ‘Wolverine’ - forget about that, too!“

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly canon but in the canon world of *X-Men*, the second half of the movie has been wiped and can be re-written as anything since Stryker is dead and is instead Mystique. This also explains how they can remake Deadpool while keeping him in the canon.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Thank you for your answer. We prefer to see answers that are not just an opinion, but that use facts and show their sources. Have you taken a look at the [tour] or the [help] yet?

Answer (score 0):

I say its not canon.  The x men franchise works best if you just ignore origins wolverine.  DOFP shows flashes from X2, not origins, when wolverine sees stryker and whigs out.  He remembers the adamatium procedure the bloody bryan singer way.  DOFP also has characters and flashes to scenes from First Class, The Last Stand and The Wolverine, but not origins.  The new timeline then proceeds to erase the events of all of the original trilogy leaving future Wolverine the only one who remembers it.

Comment: This answer seems wholly opinion-based. I think the OP was looking for an answer based on some established fact like an interview, quote from the director, quote from Marvel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that Origins will no longer be canon as of the new timeline from DOFP onward. X-Men Apocalypse is based in the 80's and wolverine is supposedly in this film so it may or may not include an explanation. To include origins would leave lots of confusing continuity as Xavier is like really old whereas in apocalypse he is now being played by James McAvoy and many other mistakes will occur as new information of film information(and follow up films) are release. Your opinion is your own but easily...treat it as non canon

Basically your answer is NON CANON
or that's what it's shaping up to be.

Comment: Answers based on personal opinion are generally less valuable than those based on evidence. Aside from your own issues with the casting and apparent age of Professor X, do you have any good reason for thinking that Origins is (or will be) non-canon?

Answer (score 0):

In X-Men Origins, Logan and Victor Creed (Sabretooth) are shown fighting in the Vietnam War before being sent to execution.

In Days of Future Past, politicians and generals are seen to be signing the Paris Peace Accords, ending America's war with North Vietnam. This means that Logan and Victor's war service is before the moment Mystique attacks Trask at the Paris Peace Accords, and the interruption by Logan, Hank, Xavier and Erik, and therefore does not get affected.

Therefore, this means that Logan and Victor surviving the firing squad and joining Team X with Stryker is before future Logan changes anything in the timeline, meaning the timeline continued with Logan and Victor joining Team X.

So, technically, the way it works out, Logan and Victor fight in the Vietnam War before Victor kills one of the officers. They survive the firing squad and join Stryker's Team X and do work there. One morning, future Logan wakes up in present Logan's body and does the stuff in Days of Future Past. And then, it changes. Mystique, pretending to be Stryker, recovers Logan's body, but Mystique slips up and the real Stryker manages to get the body. He then experiments on Logan, but Wolverine escapes as in Apocalypse.

But there is still the problem with the two Wade Wilson/Deadpools. Unless there are two Wade Wilsons that coincidentally both talk a lot (well, the first had his mouth sewn up, but before that) and both decide to call themselves Deadpool and both get powers, I got no idea on that.

So, simply, yes, X-Men Origins: Wolverine should be canon, but no, X-Men: Origins is not canon.

In even more simpler terms,

NO

Answer (score -2):

#### Neither of them are canon. The movies may possess their own acceptable storylines but they are not the canon character.

- The movies suffer from adaptation degradation.
- The canon material is found in the comics where Wolverine is experimented on by Strucker and has served in nearly every military conflict since the Civil War.
- If you are interested in a detailed accounting of the canon comic character, I suggest the **[The Wolverine Files](http://www.wolverinefiles.com/)**, which give a complete character accounting of his history through the comics and the inconsistencies in the character's development over the decades since his creation.

Comment: Just because they're not part of the comic book canon doesn't mean they're not part if the canon of the X-Men movies (and spin-offs). There can be more than one canon and continuity.