# How does the new Deadpool movie relate to X-Men Origins: Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016, x-men-origins-wolverine

Right so seeing as the new Deadpool movie shows the origins of Deadpool: specifically, he got cancer... blah blah had to get him the healing factor from Wolverine.

But that makes no sense — they used the same actor, so I'm assuming there must be some connection, right... right?

Comment: Well, as we know, *X-Men: Days of Future Past* significantly messed with the X-Men’s timeline (see e.g. Jean Grey and Professor X suddenly still being alive), so maybe it messed with the events of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* too.

Comment: Alternate timelines, different Wade Wilson, who knows?

Comment: At this stage you have to just accept that continuity is not very important when it comes to Superhero movies. 15 Spider-man reboots, multiple X-Men timelines, the Thing going commando. Nothing makes sense.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Professor X was already alive before the whole time stuff in that movie happened.

Comment: @MatthewGreen: the word “before” is tricky when it comes to time travel.

Comment: I believe the timeline excuse is a pretty poor get out of jail free card.

Comment: @Paul: what jail? They made another movie, and they tried to write the script to be as entertaining as possible in the hope of recouping the tens of millions of dollars it costs to make one of these things. The people who care that Ryan Reynolds played a character called Deadpool in a fairly terrible 2009 movie will not make or break this movie’s success at the box office.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Very true, very true!

Comment: The timeline was rewritten in days of future past, so they kind of have a fresh start with him. That's if he's tied to the X-Men franchise, which it sounds like he might not be.

Comment: @XYZ “That's if he's tied to the X-Men franchise, which it sounds like he might not be.” — [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)), it’s meant to be part of the Fox X-Men series of movies. It’s got Colossus in it at least.

Comment: Oh, and because I forgot to make this joke before: how does the new Deadpool movie relate to X-Men Origins: Wolverine? Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Short answer: We don't **know** because *Deadpool* hasn't come out, but Ryan Reynolds (who was heavily involved in writing/producing the movie) was pretty clear that his *Deadpool* character is a brand new character:

> “Deadpool appearing in ‘Origins’ is not the Deadpool we are representing in this film, in any way shape or form.” [src](http://www.ibtimes.com/deadpool-movie-ryan-reynolds-new-film-connected-x-men-origins-wolverine-2004670)

Longer answer: Wade Wilson in *Deadpool* is not the same person that was portrayed in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, and will have nothing in common beyond happening to be played by the same actor. In fact, the primarily motivation for the movie being made was Reynold's desire to "do Deadpool right".

The trailer clearly shows the movie telling an origin story for Deadpool, that he was sick and used an experimental treatment to get better, and that he gained a healing factor while suffering serious scars on his face. We see none of the story of Stryker building Deadpool as a conglomerate of mutant powers in *Deadpool*.

They are so different I think it's obviously not related, but the major differences:

- He only has one "mutant" power that we know of
- He wears his traditional black/red suit
- His mouth is not sewn shut, in fact he's *really* chatty

---

On a side-note: the reason it's the same actor is because the actor is the reason the movie got made. Ryan Reynolds was very interested in doing a real Deadpool movie, after playing such a horrid version of him in the *Origins* movie, that he personally spearheaded the *Deadpool* movie, with himself in the starring role:

> we didn’t quite get Deadpool right there. So this is kind of an opportunity to put the most authentic version possible on the screen. [src](http://www.ibtimes.com/deadpool-movie-ryan-reynolds-new-film-connected-x-men-origins-wolverine-2004670)

Comment: I hope there’s some sort of fourth-wall-breaking reference to *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

Comment: Yeah, with any luck Deadpool will say "unlike that asshat from Origins" or something.

Comment: [Deadpool appearing in ‘Origins’ is not the Deadpool we are representing in this film, in any way shape or form.”](http://www.ibtimes.com/deadpool-movie-ryan-reynolds-new-film-connected-x-men-origins-wolverine-2004670)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite there's a clear and obvious reference to *Green Lantern* so I'm very hopeful there will also be a *Wolverine* one.

Comment: @phantom42 yeah, I knew he had said it somewhere; Murphy beat you to the quote, though :)

Comment: but not a linked source :p

Comment: @SJuan76 That was obviously the motivation for Fox to make the movie, but Reynolds put a lot of effort into filming a test screening etc. because he genuinely liked the project.

Comment: @Michael: from the Deadpool trailer *trailer*: "[...from the studio that inexplicably sewed his f*cking mouth shut the first time...](http://youtu.be/QPZHBjyUGhQ)" it's not, so far as I know, in the film, but the teaser trailer for the trailer clearly comments on the Wolverine incarnation.

Comment: ", and will have nothing in common beyond happening to be played by the same actor." ... And both being named Wade...

Answer (score 7):

No, they're not maintaining continuity between the two.

> “Deadpool appearing in Origins is not the Deadpool we are representing
>   in this film, in any way shape or form,”

Reynolds told EW’s Jess Cagle and Jessica Shaw Saturday on EW Live on SiriusXM.

Comment: Thank God. Of course, they can still reference the other Deadpool somehow. I hope.

Answer (score 7):

While Wade Wilson was turned into a character vaguely similar to Deadpool in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, that specific story has been effectively undone by the events of *Days of Future Past*.

The new *Deadpool* movie does, however, exist within the post-DOFP [x-men-cinematic-universe](/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe).  Producer Simon Kinberg  [recently explained](http://movieweb.com/x-men-apocalypse-deadpool-gambit-connection-universe/) this:

> But I work on all of those films in one capacity or another, either as a producer on all of them and as a writer on Fantastic Four and this movie, so I'm certainly aware of all the different stories we're telling at the same time, and they all are part of a larger fabric now, **and so the world of Deadpool, the world of Gambit, exists in a post-X-Men: Days of Future Past post-X-Men: Apocalypse world** where all of these stories are the same as our shared history. The same way that each of us of different ages knows about Nixon and knows about Reagan and knows about 9/11, **our fictitious events like the stadium dropping on the White House in 1973 is part of the world in which Gambit, Deadpool, Wolverine 3 on forward exists.**

In the movie, Deadpool visits The Xavier School for Higher Learning, and interacts with Colossus and Negasonic Teenage Warhead, both members of the X-Men. Additionally, Colossus repeatedly attempts to recruit Deadpool to the X-Men team.

More importantly, Deadpool is revealed to only have more recently gained his mutant abilities as an adult, as a result of experimentation, long after the events of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

Breaking the fourth wall repeatedly, Deadpool references the previous X-Men movies. He has an action figure of Wade Wilson from the *Origins* movie, and comments that it's hard to keep the timelines of the X-Men movies straight.

[image: "deadpool" action figure]

Answer (score 3):

To quote from CinemaBlend's [review of the movie's script](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Deadpool-Script-Review-This-Role-Could-Make-Ryan-Reynolds-An-Icon-21158.html):

> Of course there’s a problem in turning Deadpool into a movie, it’s a problem caused by X-Men Origins: Wolverine where the character was first introduced, abused, ruined, and then killed. This script eliminates that problem brilliantly by, well, mocking it. The script never comes right out and mentions Wolverine, it’s all accomplished through one specific subtle reference, which says everything that needs to be said. It’s as though **the character of Deadpool exists in a world where Wolverine is a movie that he’s seen, and hates.** Deadpool literally throws everything Wolverine did to screw up this character in the trash can, and then spends the rest of the movie endlessly poking fun at the celebrity of Hugh Jackman.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain continuity, DOFP has rewritten that timeline as well so it doesn't matter if it connects to XMen Origins. It can be the same character with a different timeline and by default a different path in this version.