# Which movies has Wade Wilson been in?

Tags: movie, deadpool, marvel

I recently read that the Wade Wilson character was in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, before he became Deadpool.  I had forgotten this because it has been a while since I saw that movie.

**What other movies has the Wade Wilson character been in, and what is the brief synopsis of the cinematic back story of Wade Wilson?** Are any of Wade Wilson's movie appearances in the MCU?

[image]

Comment: Well, since the MCU is the acronym for the Marvel (=Disney) Cinematic Universe, and X-Men (including the Wolverine movies and the upcoming *Deadpool* movie) are 20th Century Fox' property, Wade Wilson has been in **0** MCU movies so far, since Marvel (/Disney) do(es)n't actually have the rights to the character. A brief synopsys of his MCU appearance is therefore as follows (**extremely** brief): " "   Yup, that's about it.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: yeah I think you’re probably right.

Comment: Closely related but *not* a duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99251/how-does-the-new-deadpool-movie-relate-to-x-men-origins-wolverine

Comment: "I had forgotten this because it has been a while since I saw that movie." It's probably for the best to continue to forget about it. That's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Character description:**

> Deadpool was depicted as a supervillain when he made his first appearance [...] but has since evolved into the role of an antihero. Deadpool is a disfigured and mentally unstable mercenary with the superhuman ability of an accelerated healing factor. He is known as the "Merc with a Mouth" because of his talkative nature and tendency to break the fourth wall, which is used by writers to create humorous effect.
>   <sub>- [source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool)</sub>

- [Wade Wilson](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Wade_Wilson#X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine), aka Deadpool, was in *[X-Men Origins: Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine)*. He was played by Ryan Reynolds.

  [image]
- He is getting a sort of reboot in his own film, *[Deadpool](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool_(film))* with Reynolds reprising the role. This film is part of the continuity of the X-Men films.

  [image]

---

Deadpool is part of the continuity of the X-Men films. The X-Men films are not part of the MCU as the rights are owned by [Twentieth Century Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Century_Fox) while Disney owns [Marvel Studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Studios). Therefore the X-Men film universe and and the Marvel Cinematic Universe do not share any continuity.

Comment: It's good that it's not in the MCU, because Deadpool has a history of kinda... breaking the universe...

Answer (score 7):

*X-Men Origins: Wolverine* is actually not part of [the MCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe). It’s part of [the X-Men film series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_(film_series)), produced by 20th Century Fox.

Prior to *Deadpool (2016)*, that was Wade Wilson/Deadpool’s [only appearance on the silver screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool#Film), so no, we haven’t seen that character in the MCU. (In short, 20th Century Fox owns the movie rights to “mutants” from Marvel Comics, which includes Deadpool.)

In *Origins*, Wade Wilson is part of the mutant mercenary group including Wolverine, Sabretooth, and [Will.i.am from the Black-Eyed Peas](https://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/webdr05/2013/4/23/8/enhanced-buzz-30756-1366721816-2.jpg). Later in the movie, he is both imbued with the powers of several deal mutants by Major Stryker (making him “the dead pool”), and (as [the Deadpool teaser trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaQjTcRkCNk) noted) inexplicably has his f—ing mouth sewed shut. He fights Wolverine on top of a cooling tower and gets his head chopped off, although because he has a healing power like Wolverine’s, [this may not have mattered very much](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onvfnqj-LbI).

The upcoming Deadpool movie [is also part of the X-Men film series](http://comicbook.com/2014/10/03/simon-kinberg-confirms-deadpool-movie-is-part-of-shared-x-men-ci/) (it has Colossus in it!), and so theoretically shares continuity with *Origins*, but it will essentially [ignore that film entirely](http://www.ibtimes.com/deadpool-movie-ryan-reynolds-new-film-connected-x-men-origins-wolverine-2004670) in relation to Wade Wilson/Deadpool’s character history.

Comment: "the mercenary group including Wolverine, Sabretooth, and Will.i.am from the Black-Eyed Peas" ^_^ John Wraith... he didn't exactly portray his stage persona.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: he did not. I just like to remind myself that the first solo Wolverine movie having the guy behind ‘Where Is The Love’ and ‘I Gotta Feeling’ in the cast is a thing that happened.

Comment: Everyone knows Wade Wilson was also in Blade Trinity, he was just undercover and using a different alias.

Comment: @CBredlow Yes, I believe his undercover name was ["F**k You"](http://38.media.tumblr.com/cf18fd2c8b9de91177ce087ffde1c2e0/tumblr_n9su912yHW1tiiqnto1_500.gif)

Answer (score 2):

### 2 appearances of characters named Wade Wilson

Both *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* and *Deadpool* feature characters named Wade Wilson who are played by Ryan Reynolds.

### 1 appearance of the Wade Wilson character from *Deadpool*

Quoting from [CinemaBlend's review](https://web.archive.org/web/20101017070433/http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Deadpool-Script-Review-This-Role-Could-Make-Ryan-Reynolds-An-Icon-21158.html) of the movie's script:

> the character of Deadpool exists in a world where Wolverine is a movie that he’s seen, and hates

### 0 appearances of Wade Wilson in the MCU

The character is owned by Fox and therefore had never appeared in the MCU (which is owned by Disney)