# Which X-Men movies should I watch before Deadpool?

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2016

I want to watch Deadpool, but I have heard the character has appeared in X-Men series too. My question is, if I watch X-Men before Deadpool, will it enhance my interest in the Deadpool character?

Comment: Not a movie as such, but theres a lot of background in the comics.   Start at http://hellocomic.com/deadpool/c1/p1   and read forward.

Comment: "Will it enhance my interest" is possibly too opinionated a question to ask of other people. Please consider rewording your question more objectively. Great suggestions [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Answer (score 38):

To understand the film, none.

To understand the jokes, you need to watch or know [X-Men Origins: Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine) and [X-Men: Days of Future Past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past).

Those jokes and all the other references (almost) are listed in [this Movies & TV answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/what-were-all-the-references-in-deadpool). (It’s full of **spoilers**.)

Colossus's character did appear in X2, X-Men: The Last Stand and X-Men: Days of Future Past, but none of his past roles have any importance for this film and he is even played by different <strike>actor</strike> actors.

<sub>Note: There are many non X-men film jokes/references too like Green Lantern, Taken (film series) etc etc which you can check from above Movies and TV answer.</sub>

Comment: It is possible that understanding the jokes may require watching "Origins: Wolverine", but I doubt your total lifetime happiness will be increased through such a decision.  OTOH, Days of Future Past is awesome.  Watching at least one Jean-Luc Picfessor (say, X-Men or X2) will also help get at least one joke.

Comment: @Yakk:   I liked Origins:Wolverine.  At the very least the intro sequence was awesome.

Answer (score 10):

Deadpool only appears in the movie [X-Men Origins: Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/), as Deadpool. and this representation of Deadpool is different to the rebooted origin story of Deadpool, as told in the newly released movie.

If you want to know more, albeit *alternate*, backstory on Deadpool/Wade Wilson, then I'd recommend you watch it.

But you can comfortably watch the new movie with no knowledge of Deadpool as it contains a well defined, new origin story for the character.

Comment: that was not deadpool, it was an aberration. Thank god Days of Future Past came along and took it out of existence

Comment: @Cearon O'Flynn. At the time of the move, that WAS Deadpool/Wade Wilson. And yes, it was monstrous and i praise the heavens for the days of future past ret-con. Which is why i specifically mentioned it as **Alternate** backstory.

Comment: I know I know just really hate that that thing is a version of deadpool

Comment: @Cearon O'Flynn. It genuinely made me angry when i saw it, at least it's over now

Comment: I'm sure nearly everyone here is aware — but the OP might not be — that the abomination of poor writing that was Deadpool/Wade Wilson was played by the same actor as the 2016 Deadpool— Ryan Reynolds.  However, Ryan's portrayal is immensely better in the new movie (so don't let his presense make you think there's continuity here that isn't).  _Let's just say 2016's Deadpool is from the world's-greatest-comic-universe Earth-616 and that one in X-Men Origins: Wolverine is from Earth-57748._

Answer (score 1):

As [detailed here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117023/which-movies-has-wade-wilson-been-in?rq=1), only *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* featured a character called Wade Wilson/Deadpool.

Obviously we have no idea what will enhance your interest in Deadpool, but the new Deadpool movie has no continuity links with that movie.

If you’re entirely unaware of the X-Men series of movies, a couple of the references and jokes in the new movie won’t make much sense to you. But as long as you’ve seen one of X-Men 1–3, and either First Class or Days of Future Past, I think you’re good on that score too.

Answer (score 1):

As Ankit said, you need to see nothing to enjoy it, and X-Men: Origins will allow you to get some of the jokes about that.

But there are like 2-3 jokes about Ryan Reynolds being also Green Lantern that you would really enjoy if you see Green Lantern first.