# Are the X-Men movies related to Deadpool?

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order, deadpool

**No spoilers, please!**

My friend and I plan to see Deadpool soon, but she hasn't seen any of the X-Men movies. Would she benefit at all from having seen the X-Men movies (or at least, any specific ones) before Deadpool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which X-Men movies should I watch before Deadpool?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119838/which-x-men-movies-should-i-watch-before-deadpool)

Comment: @HBhatia Yeah, I'll accept that. I didn't see that question come up in the list of suggestions. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deadpool makes a few references to events of Days of Future Past, lots of references to the character of Wolverine (and Wolverine: Origins in particular), and comments on the X-Men franchise as a whole. (There are also a few references to the Green Lantern movie).

Some jokes will go over the heads of people who haven't seen those movies, but there are a *lot* of jokes.