# Which X-Men timeline does Deadpool belong to (post X-Men movies)

Tags: x-men, marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

This is my first post, so I'm not sure if this is a repeat question or not. I appreciate any answers you guys can give me.

Given that X-Men: Days of Future Past retconned the entire X-Men series, but it was released before the new Deadpool movie (plus Wolverine: Origins), which timeline does Deadpool belong to? I'm assuming since Colossus is present in the movie, he would be part of the "fixed" timeline - i.e. post DoFP. But given that Deadpool's time is part of both the "bad" timeline and part of the "fixed" one, would his timeline be retconned as well?

Bonus Points: Would he be aware of the whole thing, given that he is eventually aware that he is in a comic in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is X-Men Origins: Wolverine canon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/is-x-men-origins-wolverine-canon)

Comment: He is definitely aware: in the movie, when Colossus says he's taking him to see Professor X, he says "Which one, McAvoy or Stewart? These timelines are so confusing."

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate of the earlier one: even after the retcon of Origins there is still a genuine question how Wade Wilson plugs into the X-Men timeline, if at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Deadpool character that appears in the solo *Deadpool* movie, as far as we have been told, is part of the post-*Days of Future Past* revised timeline. That movie removed any trace of the Weapon XI character usually identified as "Deadpool" from *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*. (Note that Stryker only uses the term "Deadpool" once, and it's not clear that he's using it as a name/nickname.)

There's still a problem with the timeline, though, in that much of *Origins* happened before Wolverine's interference split the the timeline. In other words, Logan still served in the Agent X program with a mutant named Wade Wilson.

However, all indications are that the two people named Wade Wilson are **not** the same people:

- *X-Men Origins* Wade Wilson was already mutant from the time we met him, during or soon after the Vietnam War. He was a part of the Agent-X / Weapon-X program from the beginning, and as far as we know, never has any kind of life outside of it. His mutation was a very basic type of enhanced speed/skill/agility (primarily swordsmanship.)
- *Deadpool* Wade Wilson was a former special operations soldier (we're never told where, I don't think) living in New York City in the mid 2010's. When we meet him, his mutation has not yet manifested, until he joins the "new" branch of the Weapon-X program and has it forced out of him. Prior to that he appears to have established a life for himself as a mercenary. This character's mutation is an incredibly rapid healing factor.

The only reasonable in-universe explanation for this is that the two characters are just two totally different people who both happened to be named Wade Wilson. (Presumably, if Deadpool ever runs into Wolverine, we will get a fourth-wall-breaking explanation for this mess.)

Comment: They also look pretty similar...

Comment: `as far as we have been told` by whom?

Answer (score 4):

There's been no Word of God on the subject to my knowledge due to the lack of oversight of the Cinematic Universe. However, what we do know is that:

- Days of Future Past supposedly overwrote the existing cinematic continuity going
  forward from 1973, erasing the original three movies. Because of the
  time period, that would still allow for all the characters, including
  Deadpool, Emma Frost & Gambit, to still be around, but in different
  version than they were. The parts everyone loathes in Wolverine:
  Origins takes place at least 6 years after the Vietnam War (which
  ended in 1975).
- The X-Men's Blackbird in Deadpool more closely resembles the one from First Class than the one from the original X-men movie, despite being closer in time to the first three X-Men movies
- We see Colossus is less Americanized than he was in the first 3
  films, retaining a thick Russian accent, which is indicative by some that he came to America later than in the original timeline.
- Deadpool specifically asks the X-Men who's playing Professor X now... due to the Genre Savvy-ness of the character, this would be within his character to realize that something changed.

So I'm on the "fixed timeline" side of things.